# Javascript button click() does not trigger action

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

Calling the click() method on a button node in https://bigquery.cloud.google.com does not trigger the actual click function. I am essentially building a chrome extension which monitors the working of the queries in this site and at some point, I want to trigger the click event on the Run Query button so that the query is run. But I dont see that happening. Adding my own click() handler for that button seems to be triggered but Google's REST call does not seem to happen and so the query is never run.

I believe this was working in Chrome v46 but once I upgraded it to v47 today, it seems to have stopped working. I could not verify this though as I am having trouble installing v46 on my Mac. Could this be the reason or is there any other limitation that would block me from doing this? The button is actually described as below and seems to be built over AngularJS.

```
<jfk-button
  aria-disabled="true" 
  class="query-run jfk-button goog-inline-block jfk-button-disabled jfk-button-primary" 
  disabled="disabled"
  jfk-button-style="PRIMARY" 
  jfk-on-action="qbCtrl.startQuery()" 
  ng-disabled="!qbCtrl.canRunQuery()"
  ng-show="!qbCtrl.queryRunning"
  role="button"
  style="-webkit-user-select: none;"
>
  Run Query
</jfk-button>`
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the .click() function binds an event listener it will not actually perform the click action. You're looking for .trigger('click') I believe. I moved this to a comment instead of an answer because I'm not sure if this satisfies your requirement